# How far into the sky does the corpse of Jormungandr extend in the Day After Ragnarok setting?

Tags: savage-worlds

I’m running a weekly Savage Worlds campaign using the “Day After Ragnarok” setting.

The premise of this setting is that Hitler, realizing that the war was lost, directed his Occult researchers to bring about Ragnarok.  They succeeded in summoning Jormungandr, the Midgard Serpent, but before it could fully materialize into our dimension and encircle the world, Truman ordered a B-29 carrying an atom bomb to fly into its head, killing it.

The corpse, roughly 8k miles long and 300 miles wide, crashed to earth, causing catastrophic destruction.

My question is this:  **is there a Setting-As-Written explanation as to how high into the sky the corpse of Jormungandr extends?**

My own guess would be somewhere between 50 and 75 miles from sea level, factoring in the 'facts' that a snake’s body is probably not a perfect cylinder, compression/collapse on impact, cratering, etc.?  But I'd love to know if there is an official answer.  I'd ask on the Atomic Overmind forums, but they appear to be overrun with spam.

Comment: Setting specific questions are not at all out of bounds! (Except maybe asking about events in novels, like asking about the events of the Forgotten Realms books). Questions about the setting info derived from the RPG books is fair game. I've asked Deadlands setting questions myself.

Answer (score 4):

On page 10 of the Day After Ragnarok source book there is a small image of document describing the findings of the Experimental Ophiurgy Group.  Putting on my "cheaters" to read the super small text, I discovered a paragraph describing the physical details of the corpse of Jormungandr:

> According to Project estimates, the Serpent is slightly over 8,000 miles long, and 250 miles in body diameter. The head is rather wider; at its highest point (an eyebrow ridge roughly on the former site of Cairo) it stretches 272 miles into the atmosphere.

Of course, that is highest point (the eyebrow ridge).  The rest of the corpse is no doubt lower.

The document referenced above can be found on the Atomic Overmind web site [here](http://www.atomicovermind.com/previews/DAR_letter_03.pdf).

Comment: Wow. That puts more than half its body-height in the Low Earth Orbit altitudes. For comparison, the International Space Station's orbit lies between 254 and 258 miles above sea level.

Comment: Yeah... seems super high.  I don't imagine that it maintains a perfectly cylindrical shape as it rests on the ground, though.  One wonders what the weather effects would be of something like that.

Comment: Almost certainly catastrophically handwavium-inducing. ;) As a GM, one could justify pretty much any effect that seems fun, or equally (due to its reality-warping nature) ignore any logical ones that seem inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

I can't recall any specific numbers, but it was stated that when Sir Edmund Hillary scaled the Serpent (*rimshot*), he required a special ophi-tech suit to survive (Page 10 of DAR Setting Book). So it sounds like it goes up to the [upper atmosphere](http://www.srh.noaa.gov/srh/jetstream/atmos/layers.htm).

Comment: Citation would be nice.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing @Sitting-Duck's  answer to include the page number.